# Git Squash Not Working

Tags: git, vim, git-rebase, git-squash

I am trying to use `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and this page is shown:

[image]

As seen on the picture, I am trying to squash 6 commits into one. However, when I save the file, I am not shown another editor for me to give a new commit message for the squashed commits. I also don't see any changes to the commit. Nothing has been squashed at all.

I am wondering if it has anything to do with the wrong vim version? Because I get

> Sorry, bufexplorer 7.4.12 required Vim 7.3 or greater with patch1261 and patch1264.
>   Error detected while processing /Users/jeffreyyong/.vim/plugged/vim-gutentags/plugin/gutentags.vim:
>   line    8:
>   gutentags: this plugin requires vim >= 7.4.
>   UltiSnips requires Vim >= 7.4
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

when I do `git rebase -i HEAD~10` in the beginning.

Comment: bufexplorer seems to be a plugin you added, right ? Do you have the same error launching vim alone (not from git) ?
I think it is not linked but try to disable bufexplorer

Comment: When I launch vim alone, I don't get the bufexplorer error. But I am wondering if that is what caused the failure of `git squash`?

Comment: It looks like Git uses a different Vim than the one you are using for coding.